# Javascript and CSS table header colors

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a Javascript function when this returns a particular value I would like to change the colors of various table header using their id.

How can I change the colour of a table header in javascript I know how in CSS, or should I somehow conditionally call the CSS to do this?

Thanks,
Van

Comment: You would conditionally change the CSS with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Javascript you'll want to change the class name of the table header in question.

This way you will keep your styles in you CSS and simply switch out the class name on the header, thus changing the style.

I suggest using the [jQuery Javascript framework](http://jquery.com/) to make your life a lot easier and using its `addClass()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Change the element class with another class defined in your CSS stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('headerID').style.color = '#{color}';
```

See this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/55Z8K/

Answer (score 0):

You can easily manipulate CSS in Javascript. For example, this jQuery snippet changes the background colour of an element when condition 'x' is true:

```
if(x) $('#test').css('background-color', 'green');
```

… that's very simplistic of course: it would be far better to change the relevant element's *class* to something else, and define the various class styles in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the return of the function, you could add/remove a class from the element, causing its colors to change.

```
document.getElementById('FOO').className += 'new-class'
```

Alternatively, you can change the style of an element in JavaScript in the following way

```
document.getElementById('FOO').style = { color: '#FFF', backgroundColor: '#000' };
```

Refer to [This reference](http://noobflash.com/set-style-dynamically-with-javascript/) on the JavaScript names of style options.